# React transition group - Don't animate children

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-transition-group

I'm using `react-transition-group` to animate a router switch in React:

```
    <CSSTransitionGroup transitionName="zoom" transitionEnterTimeout={200} transitionLeaveTimeout={200}>
        <Switch key={key} location={this.props.location}>
            <Route path={this.props.match.url+"/tasks/:task_id"} component={SingleTask} key={'none'} />
            <Route slug={this.props.match.params.project_slug} path={this.props.match.url+"/"} render={(params) => (
                <ProjectIndex {...params} slug={this.props.match.params.project_slug} />
            )} key={'none'}  />
        </Switch>
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
```

It was also triggering the animation whenever any sub-routes change. So, to get around that I'm getting the pathname using `this.props.location.pathname`, then using some really gross code to get the last segment:

```
pathname = pathname.split('?')[0].split('/').filter(function (i) { return i !== ""}).slice(-1)[0];
```

...and if it's 'tasks', 'activity' or 'notes, I'm just setting the key to `'noanimate'` (i.e some generic string so the switch doesn't notice):

```
    switch(pathname){
        case 'tasks':
        case 'activity':
        case 'notes':
            key = 'noanimate';
            break;
        default:
            key = pathname;
            break;
    }
```

Now, the redirect from `/project` to `/project/tasks` does a double transition as it goes from `'project'` to `'noanimate'`, and I'm not sure whether I'm meant to write some even worse string manipulation just to get either the last or second-last term, depending on whether it's 'tasks'/'activity'/'notes' or any other string.

Is there a better solution, or is that... just how we're meant to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem so I wrote my own solution: [switch-css-transition-group](https://github.com/melounek/switch-css-transition-group)

after install you can rewrite your code to:

```js
import SwitchCSSTransitionGroup from 'switch-css-transition-group'

<SwitchCSSTransitionGroup location={this.props.location} transitionName="zoom" transitionEnterTimeout={200} transitionLeaveTimeout={200}>
    <Route path={this.props.match.url+"/tasks/:task_id"} component={SingleTask} key={'none'} />
    <Route slug={this.props.match.params.project_slug} path={this.props.match.url+"/"} render={(params) => (
        <ProjectIndex {...params} slug={this.props.match.params.project_slug} />
    )} key={'none'}  />
</SwitchCSSTransitionGroup>
```

It basically go throw all routes inside this "Switch" and using `matchPath` function recognize if some route is properly matching.

Comment: Perfect! That certainly seemed to do the trick.

Cheers Melounek